# java.util.logging.FileHandler clear logs

Tags: java, logging

I have a `Logger` with a `FileHandler` handler. 
Is it any easy way to delete all logs files written by it and clear currently opened file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no out-of-the-box method to remove these files. `FileHandler` does not expose the list of files.

I think the easiest way will be to write a `FileFilter` to match the pattern from `FileHandler` and use `File.listFiles(filter)` on the parent directory of the log files.